# I want google map like this Multiple Polyline, can Multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want  google map like this Multiple Polyline, can Multiple select.

Multiple Polyline

[image]

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var polyline;

positions = [new google.maps.LatLng(37.441883,-122.143019),
             new google.maps.LatLng(37.45296,-122.181725)];
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    $("#chkRouteLines").click(function () {
        if (!polyline || !polyline.setMap) {
          polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: positions,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            visible: true
          }); 
        }

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        polyline.setMap(map);
    } else {
        polyline.setMap(null);
    }
})


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<input id="chkRouteLines" value="click" type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can google developers documents.For example this link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Complex Polylines</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      // This example creates an interactive map which constructs a polyline based on
      // user clicks. Note that the polyline only appears once its path property
      // contains two LatLng coordinates.

      var poly;
      var map;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: {lat: 41.879, lng: -87.624}  // Center the map on Chicago, USA.
        });

        poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
          strokeColor: '#000000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 3
        });
        poly.setMap(map);

        // Add a listener for the click event
        map.addListener('click', addLatLng);
      }

      // Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
      function addLatLng(event) {
        var path = poly.getPath();

        // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
        // and it will automatically appear.
        path.push(event.latLng);

        // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          title: '#' + path.getLength(),
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```